# Postgresql role can't access its created schema

Tags: database, database-schema, postgresql-9.2

Notable information

- I am using **Postgresql 9.2** on Windows 7 64-bit. It was installed using the installer provided by [Postgresql website](http://www.postgresql.org)
- I am logged into the **postgres** database as **postgres**
- I create the **BryceTest Schema** under the **postgres** user
- I configure `search_path` to show `"brycetest, public"`

This SQL when generated by the query builder provided by pgAdmin-III works as expected

```
SELECT "DummyDataMasterTable"."Dummy_PK", 
       "DummyDataMasterTable"."DummyName"
FROM "BryceTest"."DummyDataMasterTable";
```

**BUT this doesn't**

```
SELECT DummyDataMasterTable.Dummy_PK, 
       DummyDataMasterTable.DummyName
FROM BryceTest.DummyDataMasterTable;
-------------------------------------------

ERROR:  relation "dummydatamastertable" does not exist
LINE 4:     FROM DummyDataMasterTable;
                 ^

********** Error **********

ERROR: relation "dummydatamastertable" does not exist
SQL state: 42P01
Character: 101

     FROM BryceTest.DummyDataMasterTable;
```

**Neither does**

```
SELECT 
    Dummy_PK, 
    DummyName
FROM DummyDataMasterTable;

-------------------------------
ERROR:  relation "dummydatamastertable" does not exist
LINE 4:     FROM DummyDataMasterTable;                     ^

********** Error **********

ERROR: relation "dummydatamastertable" does not exist
SQL state: 42P01
Character: 59
```

I would **THINK** that by configuring my schema `search_path` to look in my newly created schema **FIRST** it wouldn't need to have the fully qualified `schemaName.tableName`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You created the tables using double quotes and therefor they are now case-sensitive (as required by the ANSI SQL standard).

`"FooBar"` is a different name than `"Foobar"`, however `FooBar` and `foobar` are the same name (because they are not quoted).

Because you did so, you must quote the table and column names **always**.

The following works because the identifiers are not quoted:

```
create table FooBar 
(
  Some_COLUMN integer
);

select some_column from foobar;
select SOME_COLUMN FROM FOOBAR;
select Some_ColumN from FooBAR;
```

I would recommend you re-create the tables without any quotes, then you can write table and column names any way you want (as long as you don't use double quotes).

More details about (quoted) identifiers are in the manual: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-IDENTIFIERS

Comment: This worked for me! Thanks so much, I just started with learning Postgres and a gotcha that new comers should be aware of is that agAdminIII will do wrap object names in quotes. I don't think I'll be using the GUI tool from now on...

Comment: @DynaWeb: you should ***not*** be using *any* quotes. It's one of the reasons I don't like pgAdmin.